# New window in Silverlight out-of-browser application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob

In a Silverlight application that doesn't run in a browser, is it possible to create a new top-level window? Or at least a child window?

I found some solution using the [`ChildWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow%28VS.95%29.aspx) class, but even though my project is configured for Silverlight 4, that class can not be found.

I have a `UserControl` (XAML file) that I want to show as a new window. Using a tab control is not really an option unfortunately as the user has to be able to arrange windows to see more than one at once.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ChildWindow` is part of the SDK, you need to add the System.Windows.Controls.dll to access the `ChildWindow` type.

I'm not sure you can get the ChildWindow to do what you are expecting.  A ChildWindow is designed to present a window in a modal manner.   However this modal behaviour is really a function of the ChildWindow template.  It is possible to re-template to remove the modal behaviour.  However I've never tried to manipulate multiple child windows.  You could give it a go, the big question would be what happens if you close Child windows in a different order in which they were created?

In order to use a `ChildWindow` to present your `UserControl` it would probably be best for you to derive from `ChildWindow`, instead of `UserControl`.  You may even find it would ultimately be better for you create base class between your specific Xaml and ChildWindow where you would put code that is common to all your windows.

I might be worth you noting the Silverlight 5 will support multiple windows.

Comment: I will use Silverlight 5 beta and its support for creating native windows. Works great :) That will be the best solution for our project. And for completeness: [Tutorial on Silverlight 5 Native Windows](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/silverlight-5-native-operating-system/)